# Position relative and Position fixed behind

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iframe which is showing google map following css is applied on it

```
position: relative;
top: 48px;
left: -233px;
```

but when i scroll down it just comes above the bar which is showing khaleej time and social links 
[image]
I try many techniques but no use to make this iframe behind that social link bar . [Live site](http://uaepap.org/test/EducationPage.htm)

Comment: Looks fine to me, which browser are you using?

Comment: @NateB i am using chrome

Comment: I think you would typically set the wmode to `opaque`... at present it's set to `window`.  `<param name="wmode" value="opaque">`

Comment: @JosephMarikle where i have to set it or try it

Comment: @Hira unfortunately I have no idea. :S  That's why I made a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is Scribble Maps is using the flash plugin and not setting the wmode to opaque.  Without this, Flash renders on-top of everything else.  I would suggest contacting them and having them change their embed code slightly.

Forcing the z-index on the iframe, and the bottom bar won't correct this.